# How to update user information mysql using servlet

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlets

Currently I am writing to a database for users using mysql, the user has a few fields, and I would like to have them capable of updating their current user profile using a form. In the placeholder I would like to display their current information. The submit should change the information provided and update the table.

```
<h2>Update your profile</h2>
<div class="form">
    <form action="/updateprofile">
        <input type="text" name="Email_Address" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="text" name="First_Name" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="Last_Name" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input class="button" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the servlet code {not all of it just writing into the sqldb}

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Obtain submitted form data
    String firstName = req.getParameter("First_Name");
    String lastName = req.getParameter("Last_Name");
    String username = req.getParameter("User_Name");
    String email = req.getParameter("Email_Address");
    String password =req.getParameter("Password");

    try {
    //Setup the Database datasource
    Context    ctx = new InitialContext();
    Context env = ( Context )ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env" );
    DataSource ds = ( DataSource )env.lookup( "jdbc/carRentalSystem");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    //Prepare the SQL statmenet to insert the values
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO userdetails(First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Address, Password, User_Name)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    stmt.setString(1, firstName);
    stmt.setString(2, lastName);
    stmt.setString(3, email);
    stmt.setString(4, password);
    stmt.setString(5, username);

    //Execute the insert
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    conn.close();

    //Dispatch into success page
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
    requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);
}
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: where is your servlet code? what you've done in the server side?

Comment: updated with servlet code

Comment: where is `UPDATE` ?

Comment: first of all, your sql sentence is an INSERT, not an UPDATE, second, I would recommend you to specify the method in the form declaration, `method="PSOT"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this to update instead of insert into, That was a big silly mistake I apologize it took this long.